# pass variable between pages in zk

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, zk, zk-grid

I have this code in zk:

```
@Command
public void showModal(@BindingParam("languageContributionStatus") UserStatus mnoList) {
    //create a window programmatically and use it as a modal dialog.
    final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    setPickedItemSet(mnoList.getMnoList());
    map.put("mnoList", mnoList.getMnoList());

        win = (Window) Executions.createComponents("/comListMnosUser.zul", null, map);

        win.doModal();

}
```

In this code i have a page and i create a window with other page, in my other page:

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">    

 <window id="CreateList" border="normal" mode="modal" width="320px"
            apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
            viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.UserMno')">
    <label value="First Name"></label>
    <listbox model="@bind(vm.allMno)" checkmark="true" multiple="true" selectedItems="@bind(vm.mnoList)"/>
    <button id="SaveBtn" hflex="1" label="Save" onClick="@command('save', mnosL=vm.mnoList)" />
</window>

</zk>
```

Then i need save the variable mnoList to use in the previous page, but i can not use Excecution.createComponent, because i need only close the window because i have  win.doModal();

And use the variable mnoList, but i do not know how can i pass this variable to use in the other page.

Somebody can help me??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in right direction even no need to pass object as a argument with button which you did because `mnoList` is class variable or you can say ViewModel so it already available on your modal Window java class. What you can do .

1-Use same button and code something like this

```
<button id="SaveBtn" hflex="1" label="Save" onClick="@command('save')" />
```

2-In `UserMno.java` class use the method like this.And write logic to call Parent ViewModel method from Child ViewModel.

```
    @Command
    public void doReorder(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); //create a Map to store 
    params.put("param", mnoList);

        Binder bind = (Binder) view.getParent().getAttribute("binder");
        if (bind == null)
            return;
        bind.postCommand("parentclassMethodName", param);
}
```

This `parentclassMethodName` method should be in your parent ViewModel class.